# get time remaining using ajax with move_uploaded_file() php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to calculate the actual file upload time in fact with this code I find the remaining time in% of the file upload, but it doesn't work, because when it reaches 100% and I refresh the page, the files haven't yet been moved to the destination folder but I have to wait before they are moved. Any solution?

```
xhr: function(){
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
var started_at = new Date();
xhr.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', function(e){
    if( e.lengthComputable ){
        var loaded = e.loaded;
        var total = e.total;
        var progressValue = Math.round( ( loaded / total ) * 100 );
        $('section.gallery .row div .content-progress-bar .progress .progress-bar').width(progressValue+'%').change();
    }
}, false );
return xhr; 
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you. https://github.com/SiddharthaChowdhury/Async-File-Upload-using-PHP-Javascript-AJAX It was a 5 second google search.

Comment: I search an async upload. My progress bar work correctly.